# How to match high-value unicode characters using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Specifically, I want to match the range `[#x10000-#xEFFFF]`. AFAIK, the `\u` escape sequences only accept 4 hex digits, not 5. Is there a way to match higher values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 hex digits require surrogate pairs. Use the es6 'u' (unicode) flag to create surrogate pair aware regex

- https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode
- under 'Ranges and flag “u”' https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges

```
// incorrect
''.match(/[]/)

// correct
''.match(/[]/u
```

Answer (score 4):

Internally, JavaScript uses UCS-2, which is limited to the base plane. For higher-range characters, you will have to use surrogate pairs. For instance, to find U+13FFA, you can match `\uD80F\uDFFA`.

More details can be found [here](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work well within character classes in a regex. With BMP characters, you can do things like `/[a-z]/`. You can't do that with higher-range characters because JavaScript doesn't understand that surrogate pairs should be treated as a unit. You may be able to hunt around for third-party libraries that deal with this. <strike>Sadly, I don't know of any to recommend.</strike> [This one](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) might be worth a look. I've never used it, so I cannot attest to it's quality.

P.S. You may find [this shim](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2290602) useful for dealing with higher-order characters generally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var regex = /#x[1-9a-eA-E][0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g;

console.log(regex.test("#x03FFA")); // false
console.log(regex.test("#x13FFA")); // true
```

http://jsbin.com/awidew/1

mz

Comment: Uh.....no. I don't want to match that literal string. That was supposed to represent a range of high-order unicode characters.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, you want to match in your regex high-value chars :)